# How to convert a Template class to an Int

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm creating a Hash table for a homework assign, and i run trough a problem, i have a Template Structure with the key and data type

```
template<typename T, typename K>
struct Item
{
    T data;
    K key;
    state flag;
    Item() {}
    Item(T d, K k, state f) { data = d; key = k; flag = f; }
};
```

I need to convert the key (type K) to an int, how should i do?

Comment: `static_cast<int>(key);` ?

Comment: Of course it depends on what type you want to pass to the template for `K`. E.g. if it is `string` you probably have to write a template specialization that does the conversion.

Comment: And what if `K` is a type that is not naturally convertible to an `int`?

Comment: Your hash table data structure should contain the hash function as a parameteter. This function is responsible for converting K to int. You should just call it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at how the C++11 standard library handles this via [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

Comment: Why don't you set `K` to `int` and just use `Item<T, int>`?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest, but not necessarily best way: starting from the char pointer to the key and using all the bytes according to sizeof(key), cast to pointer to int and add all possible ints and take into account the extra bytes that doesn't fit the last int.  That will always return an int, but the guarantee of unique values depends on the type of the key.

---

Edit: for production code, prefer `std::hash`, as already mentioned in the comments.